# Installation error ABI INCOMPATIBLE

Tags: android, android-ndk

Sorry if it was easy, I'm a beginner.
I am trying to use NDK with cygwin.
Cygwin creat (.SO) file unde libs->armeabi folder.
When i run the application it gives me the installation Error on genymotion Nexus 4.4

Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_CPU_ABI_INCOMPATIBLE

```
Android.mk file

LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

# Here we give our module name and source file(s)
LOCAL_MODULE    := ndkfoo
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ndkfoo.c

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Comment: You should provide your makefiles for this kind of question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Genymotion supports only *x86* libraries. However, by default, the ndk generates only an *armv5* (armeabi) library.

To solve this, you can simply create a file called *Application.mk* next to your *Android.mk* file, and put inside:

```
APP_ABI := all
```

so the ndk will compile your library for all the architectures its support, including x86.

Comment: Try this but it doesn't work still unable to install. in logcat windo getting errors like. Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienceCach

Comment: The errors you get don't seem related to your issue. You can clean your build, run ndk-build, repackage your app and try again.

Comment: Thanx.Actullay i am not spacifying the correct package name in my c file.Thanx once again for your help